# random walk with a Robin (or mixed) boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, random-walk

I'm working on the random walk process of particles to compare with a pde solution. I understand the random walk algorithm for each particle's location at each time with the Neumann boundary condition. However, I don't see how to implement the random walk algorithm with the Robin(or mixed) boundary condition.

For example, we can consider the 1d convection-diffusion equation
\begin{align*}
u_{t}  + (c(x)u)_{x} = Du_{xx}, \qquad x\in [0,L], \;\ t\geq 0
\end{align*}
 with a Robin boundary condition
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}  = k u, \qquad x = 0 , L.
\end{align*}